# Where did Jobu Tupaki's name come from?

Tags: everything-everywhere-all-at-once

In *Everything Everywhere All At Once*, the villain Jobu Tupaki is the agglomeration of many Joy Wang consciousnesses from across the multiverse. I don't know if this name is just jibberish, or if it was spun out of some thread in the Daniels' collective brain.

They both start with 'Jo'... Tupac?

Answer (score 9):

In-universe, it does not seem to have any meaning.
Evelyn says:

> You’re just saying random sounds.

Out-universe too, it seems to be just nonsensical or random words, as per an interview with Daniel Kwan and Daniel Scheinert, the writers and directors of *EEAAO*. Relevant quote (emphasis mine):

> What’s in a name? Maybe nothing at all — and that’s partly the point.
> The all-powerful Jobu Tupaki, bent on destroying the multiverse to end
> the pain of her fractured relationship with Evelyn, was just the right
> **nonsensical moniker** that may have come to Kwan in a dream while he and
> his wife were brainstorming baby names.

Source: [*‘Everything Everywhere All at Once’ explained: Hot dog hands, empathy challenges and meaning in the absurd*. Los Angeles Times](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment-arts/movies/story/2022-04-14/everything-everywhere-all-at-once-explained-daniels-spoilers)

Further in the article, it states:

> In a previous draft, the name even had a back story in an even sillier
> universe populated by sentient spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

Jobu Tupakki means pocket gun in Tamil. I guess it’s the same meaning in other South Indian languages. Perhaps there’s some connection?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We do have exact words in my mother tongue (TELUGU south indian language)
I am not sure whether it makes sense for you. But as the title matches with her characterization, I assume its the reference.
Jobu means pocket, tupaki means pistol.
Jobu tupaki ~> pocket pistol

Comment: Hi, welcome to Movies & TV.  It appears that someone else has noted a similar cognate in Tamil, but do you have any evidence this is actually the _source_ of the name?